# Group objects with an identical list attribute

Tags: python, class, attributes, grouping

I have two classes:

```
class A:
   def __init__(self, name, li):
      self.b_list = li

class B:
   def __init__(self, i):
      self.i = i
```

`class A` contains a list of objects of type `class B`.

Assuming I have a list of `class A` objects, how can I group the `class A` objects that have an identical `b_list` together?

For example:

```
a_list = []

li = [B(1), B(2), B(3)]
a_list.append(A(li))

li = [B(2), B(3)]
a_list.append(A(li))

li = [B(1), B(2), B(3)]
a_list.append(A(li))
```

After processing this should give us two lists, one list with the first and third `A`, and another list with only the second `A`. Or in a nutshell:

```
result = [
   [ A([B(1),B(2),B(3)]), A([B(1),B(2),B(3)]) ],
   [ A([B(2),B(3)] ]
]
```

Comment: What is your criteria for this grouping. Are you expecting on each `append` that the grouping should be done? Or are you calling a method on your `a_list` that is in your A class that will do this grouping? Can you please provide more specifics?

Comment: Are there guaranteed to only be two groups?  That is, what if there is another `A([B(2),B(3)]` in `a_list` and a `A([B(3)])`? Or is that not possible?  Also, do you already know what the matching `b_list` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, I've removed the `name` parameter from class A, since the rest of your details omitted it.

To group your class A objects together, you're going to need to define exactly what is meant when two A objects are equal.  I've created a `__cmp__` method that will let us sort on A objects by comparing them.

Now, since your A objects are composed of B objects, you're going to need something to define what is meant by two B objects being equal.  I've created a  `__eq__` method in class B that does that.

Next, I've sorted the A instances to make grouping them easier, and added a `__str__` method to class A, and a `__repr__` method to class B so you can verify that they are being grouped together correctly.

I haven't added any error checking anywhere, so this code is a little fragile.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, li):
        self.b_list = li

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return cmp([elem.i for elem in self.b_list], 
                   [elem.i for elem in other.b_list])

    def __str__(self):
        return "A({})".format(self.b_list)

class B:
    def __init__(self, i):
       self.i = i

    def __eq__(self, other):
       return self.i == other.i

    def __repr__(self):
        return "B({})".format(self.i)

def main():

    a_list = []

    li = [B(1), B(2), B(3)]
    a_list.append(A(li))

    li = [B(2), B(3)]
    a_list.append(A(li))

    li = [B(1), B(2), B(3)]
    a_list.append(A(li))

    result = []
    last_item = None
    for item in sorted(a_list):
        if last_item and item == last_item:
            result[-1] = result[-1] + [item]
        else:
            result.append([item])
        last_item = item

    for row in result:
        print [str(elem) for elem in row]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Result:

```
['A([B(1), B(2), B(3)])', 'A([B(1), B(2), B(3)])']
['A([B(2), B(3)])']
```

Comment: I've tried to implement your solution into my actual code (what I described in my answer is simplified). It's not very long and if you happen to have a second, do you know why the sorting is not functioning? http://pastebin.com/CRZEAkuh I would expect h1,h2,h4,h3,h5 to be the  sorted order, but the code is sorting is as h1,h4,h5,h3,h2

Comment: The `__cmp__` method in class A in this answer uses `elem.i` - which is the value you instantiate B objects with.  I could have just used `elem`, but that wouldn't sort correctly since it just refers to the `B` instance.  Similarly, in your actual code, you're trying to just sort on the `service` instance.  You need to specify the attributes of your service instance that you really want to sort on (I'd use a tuple of them).

Answer (score 0):

You can sort `a_list` using the attribute b_list as a key.

```
a_list.sort(key=lambda a:a.b_list)
```

or:

```
from operator import itemgetter

a_list.sort(key=itemgetter("b_list"))
```

Comment: `sort()` will arrange them in order but it won't group them together? IE: I won't end up with two lists of `A` at the end at the end.